# Does salesforce take note of the AssertionConsumerServiceURL field in an AuthnRequest

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

[Caveat: I am new to SAML & SSO]

I have recently taken over a website that is using salesforce SSO for access to restricted areas on the site. I am developing a process whereby I can test this system (i.e. send and receive from different hosts).

The SAML request is being generated by a javascript module called passport-saml.

My problem is that the POST response gets sent to a fixed server URL (the recipient in the response SAML). I have tried configuring this for different environments via the AssertionConsumerServiceURL in the AuthnRequest SAML but this makes no difference.

Is this something that can be configured on the salesforce side?
(I currently do not have access to this configuration but can ask our IT dept to look into it)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm that the AssertionConsumerServiceURL in the SAML message was ignored by salesforce, and it uses the fixed ACS (Assertion Consumer Service) URL (which is part of the Connected App configuration) to post the response back to